# call a function when clicking shape powerpoint while sliding csharp

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-addins

I know that we can add an action when clicking a shape while sliding by 
ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action in Csharp
like my code below:

```
aromaClick = thisSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShape24pointStar, 10, 10, 20, 20);
Globals.ThisAddIn.aromaClick.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionRunProgram;
 Globals.ThisAddIn.aromaClick.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Run = "path-to-file";
```

but I wonder if I can call a function when click-shape happens? is it possible?
like call this function:

```
void hello(){
//something
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Do you want to assign a macro to run when the shape is clicked? If that is the case then the code is similar.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.aromaClick.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionRunMacro;
Globals.ThisAddIn.aromaClick.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Run = "Hello";
```

Comment: thank you for your kind comment, but I just want to call a function just inside Csharp code, like print "Hello" to screen or create a shape. if running macro, we have to do it in VB and save file name with .ppsm right?

Comment: There are two aspects to consider:
Design mode: PowerPoint provides selection events when can be hooked and they can be used to invoke your routine.
Presentation mode: This gets complicated since there are no shape specific events available here to help you besides the slide show events.

Comment: thank you! All I want is in presentation mode. But do you know any other choices I can do with clicking something in presentation mode? I just need receiving a click-something event to call a function already built in my source code. It can be a shape, a text, button whatever. can U solve it?